# Find vector x such that matrix multiplication Sx = 0

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have the following matrix 
$$S=
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 0\\
    -1 & 1 & 1\\
     1 &-1& -1\\
     0  &0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I wish to find a **non**-negative, **non**-zero, integer-valued $\vec x$ such that it is a solution to $S\vec x = 0$. How can I do this?

Comment: Take $(1,1,0)$. It is non-zero, non-negative and has integer coordinates.

Comment: Simply consider a $3\times1$ vector, $v=\{x,y,z\}$ and let $S\cdot v=0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can find this by essentially treating this as a system of linear equations and solve via Gaussian Elimination. We can see that

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} -1&1&0&0 \\ -1&1&1&0 \\ 1&-1&-1&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \end{array}\right]$$

$$\xrightarrow{R_2-R_1,R_3+R_1} \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} -1&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&-1&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \end{array}\right]$$

$$\implies R_3 : -z = 0 \implies z = 0$$

$$\implies R_1: -x + y = 0 \implies y = x.$$

Hence, our general vector that solves this system can be represented as
$$\vec{v} = \left[\begin{array}{c} y \\ y \\ 0 \end{array}\right], y \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Hence, one option could be to set the solution vector to

$$\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right].$$